# How to use t() function for a text with anchor links?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a text that I must show in 5 languages. I am using `t()` for that. The text is:

> In case of any issues, please Contact Us for assistance.

I want the phrase "Contact Us" to be a link. So this is what I have done:

```
$text = t('In case of any issues, please ')."<a href="link/to/path">".t('Contact Us')."</a>".t('for assistance');
```

I suspect that this might not be the correct way to do this as this will break the translation. I fear that the sentence will not be translated as a whole but in parts.

Am I right?

And if I am, what could be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're absolutely correct; you should never concatenate strings with `t()`, the whole point is that it uses placeholders so you don't have to. Specifically:

```
// DO NOT DO THESE THINGS
$BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at !handbook.', array('!handbook' => '<a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">'. t('the Drupal Handbooks') .'</a>'));

$ANOTHER_BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.');

$BAD_INTERNAL_LINK = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to !administer in the main menu.', array('!administer' => l(t('the Administer screen'), 'admin'));
```

Instead of those you should use the following:

```
// Do this instead.
$external_link = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="@drupal-handbook">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.', array('@drupal-handbook' => 'http://drupal.org/handbooks'));

$internal_link = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to <a href="@administer-page">the Administer screen</a> in the main menu.', array('@administer-page' => url('admin')));
```

See [Dynamic or static links and HTML in translatable strings](https://drupal.org/node/322774) for full details.

Comment: Can I use HTML inside `t()` function as you have used `<a>` tag inside your example of `t()`.

Comment: Yes, absolutely - bear in mind that's not 'my' example exactly, it's taken straight from the official documentation. Anything you see in the first example, never do - anything you see in the second example, always do :)

Comment: The general 'rule' is to avoid putting block-level tags into a translation, but there are caveats. The docs page has full details

Comment: @clive I think using html tag in `t` is not good idea because in translation has difficulty.

Comment: @zhilevan It's the recommended way to do things, though. If you read through the docs page it does make sense

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you try `l()` function and learn it, it is very good and simple.
and solution for you

```
l(t('yourtext'),'link/to/path');
```

I hope can learn you drupal base method to write your links in drupal :)

**updated Part:**

```
$link='<a href="link/to/path">'.t('Contact Us').'</a>';
t('first part of your context @link the end part of your text',array('link'=>$link));
```

Comment: l() will add the link to complete text. I only want to add it to a prat of text. How can I do that?

Comment: @DipakYadav put it before it
try something like this `$text= t('first part').l(....).t('endpart');`

Comment: @DipakYadav answer updated.

Comment: @zhilevan You shouldn't concatenate strings while using `t()`, it defeats the point of using that function in the first place

Comment: @Clive, ok but I use something like it before, I update the answer by better solution

Answer (score -3):

This solution is work for you.

```
drupal_set_message(t('Payment Method Added Successfully -  '.l('add anchor link')),'status');
```

Comment: Can you just tell me what is the wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: Look at the other examples. Read the documentation.