# How i can add a new line in my code here?

Tags: 7, forms

HI guys go to THE TEXT THAT FOLLOWS I WANT IT IN NEW LINE and help how to separate that text in 2 lines

```
 $form['kkkkkk'] = array(
          '#type'          => 'textfield',
          '#title'         => t('blablabla'),
          '#default_value' => variable_get('kkkkkkkk', ''),
          '#description'   => t('sdakgbflabfgdsbf "THE TEXT THAT FOLLOWS I WANT IT IN NEW LINE" fdghhtrjgvfnbhsgf.'),
          '#required'      => TRUE,
          '#size'          => 10,
          '#required'      => TRUE,
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options (simplified code example):

1. `$description = t('Foo.<br>Bar.');` (recommended)
2. `$description = t('Foo.') . '<br>' . t('Bar.');`

The `<br>` tag causes a line break in HTML. Both options give the same result technically. The difference is in what translators can do with it.

Option 1 treats the sentence as a unity and gives translators more flexibility. For instance, if the French translation needs to change the word order (`'Barre.<br>Fou.'`), that's possible. However the French translator would also have the possibility to leave out the line break completely.

Option 2 is more rigid. A translator could never control which part comes before the line break and which part comes after. The translator may not even know that the sentences "Foo." and "Bar." will be combined into a single page element, because they show up as separate strings in the translation interface.

Comment: Option 2 shouldn't be used - placeholders should always be used instead if you need to intersperse vars into a translated string, never concatenated according to Drupal best practices. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96622/how-to-use-t-function-for-a-text-with-anchor-links for more info and links to official docs

Comment: Clive, I would rather say that option 2 is usually not the correct solution. There are some situations where it makes sense. You can even find this pattern in Drupal core, for instance in [_filter_html_tips](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/_filter_html_tips/7).

Comment: Not to argue, but I think the reasoning in the best practice document means there _can't_ be any exceptions, and that its use in any core code is actually a bug...I shall report it and we'll see what the outcome is, will update when I get a response :)

Comment: OK, thanks for reporting it, I'm curious to see what the response is. For the record, I found the core examples by doing a regex search for `t\('.*'\) . '<.*>' . t\('.*'\)` on a Drupal 7 site. Anyway I'll update the answer to indicate that option 1 is recommended.

Comment: By the way, @Clive, I think the best practices at https://www.drupal.org/node/322774 describe a slightly different use case than this question. That page is only about links. As we all know the `<a>` tag needs to wrap text, while this question is merely about inserting a tag between two strings.

Comment: I read it as "Dynamic or static links **and** HTML in translatable strings" (emphasis mine). I see what you're saying though, could be ambiguous

Comment: I am using t() to populate the body of a mail that I am sending, Using the first option of adding <br> doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to add a line break?

Comment: @Bej By default Drupal sends plain text emails. You cannot simply turn plain text email into HTML mail by adding some tags in the body. To send HTML mail you need additional modules such as [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail).